# Focus state shouldn't change, React.JS + TailwindCSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, tailwind-css

I have a question related to tailwindcss and React. I have a property that if a `<NavItem />` is focused then the background and the text will change. `<LanguageSwitcher />` is another component, and if it is focused, I want it to not change focus state of other items in navbar. `<LanguageSwitcher />` doesn't affect URL.

Here's my code for item in navigation bar and images of how `<LanguageSwitcher />` affects focus state of other items:

[image: LanguageSwitcher isn't clicked]

[image: LanguageSwitcher is clicked]

```
import React from "react";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

interface Props {
  title: string;
  url: string;
  icon: JSX.Element;
}

const NavItem: React.FC<Props> = ({ title, url, icon }) => {
  //https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#pseudo-classes
  return (
    <Link
      to={url}
      className="text-center items-center flex-col justify-center font-medium  px-1 text-white  capitalize  hover:font-semibold  select-none group"
    >
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center mb-1 rounded-3xl px-2 py-1 group-hover:bg-btnHover group-focus:bg-btnActive group-focus:text-textActive transition-colors duration-75">
        {icon}
      </div>
      <span>{title}</span>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default NavItem;
```

Is it possible? If so, how can I do it, maybe with `useLocation` from `react-router-dom` or directly with tailwindcss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Focus" generally means the UI element the user can currently interact with. I think you are conflating "focus state" with "active state". I'm guessing you want the `Link` to remain "active" while other UI elements have, or might not have, "focus", and are being interacted with. Switch to using the `NavLink` component and conditionally apply the "active" state CSS classname.

Here's an example<sup>*****</sup>:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

interface Props {
  title: string;
  url: string;
  icon: JSX.Element;
}

const NavItem: React.FC<Props> = ({ title, url, icon }) => {
  //https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#pseudo-classes
  return (
    <NavLink
      to={url}
      className="text-center items-center flex-col justify-center font-medium  px-1 text-white  capitalize  hover:font-semibold  select-none group"
    >
      {({ isActive }: { isActive: boolean }) => (
        <>
          <div
            className={
              [
                "flex items-center justify-center mb-1 rounded-3xl px-2 py-1 group-hover:bg-btnHover transition-colors duration-75"
                isActive ? "group-focus:bg-btnActive group-focus:text-textActive" : null
              ]
                .filter(Boolean)
                .join(" ")
            }
          >
            {icon}
          </div>
          <span>{title}</span>
        </>
      )}
    </NavLink>
  );
};

export default NavItem;
```

****Note:** I've just guessed/plucked the CSS classnames that looked like they were related to the "focus/active" CSS styling, you will want to double-check the actual classes in your implementation.*

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!
I corrected some CSS classnames in your answer and everything works as needed.